# Ping not working from tap interface attached to bridge interface with ip on same subnet as that of bridge to outside

Tags: interface, ping, tap

My requirement is to create a multiple tap interfaces, each with ip address on same subnet.

I tried this by creating a bridge

```
               br0 (192.168.1.199)
     ___________|_____________________________________
     |                    |       |      |      |     |
   eth0                  tap0    tap1   tap2   tap3   tap4
                (192.168.1.150)  (.151) (.152) (.153) (.154)
```

I need all the tap interface be reachable from external PC. When i ping from tap0 to external computer say 192.168.1.200

```
ping -I tap0 192.168.1.200 -- the ping is not going through.
```

But when i ping from 192.168.1.200 to 192.168.1.150 (tap0) it is working, but i get the mac address of the bridge (br0)

I have two problems:

1. How to ping from tap interface to external
2. How to get the mac address of the right tap interface, when pinged from outside.

Comment: This is better suited in [Serverfault](http://serverfault.com/)